# Get json, image url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I would like to some how query a url [URL Here](http://www.airport-data.com/api/ac_thumb.json?m=C822AF) and then display the image result which looks like this

```
{"status":200,"count":1,"data":[{
    "image":"http:\/\/www.airport-data.com\/images\/aircraft\/thumbnails\/001\/288\/001288330.jpg",
    "link":"http:\/\/www.airport-data.com\/aircraft\/photo\/001288330.html",
    "photographer":"magnaman"
  }]
}
```

into a div (div id will be called images). I would need to replace this current code:  as it does not load the image and I am not sure how to modify it to do so. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
var imageurl;
      $.get('http://www.airport-data.com/api/ac_thumb.json?m=+value.hex', function (response) { 
        imageurl = response;
        if (imageurl == ""){
            $( "#images" ).attr('src', "imageerror.jpg");
        }
        else {
            $( "#images" ).attr('src', imageurl);

        }

      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed up the variable name a tiny bit, but this should do what you need, you just need to access the image property from the object correctly. Also, check out the included codepen I created to simulate how to actually set an image somewhere with jquery.

```
$.get('http://www.airport-data.com/api/ac_thumb.json?m=C822AF', function(res) {
    var imgUrl = res.data[0].image

    if (imgUrl == "") {
        $("#images").attr('src', "imageerror.jpg");
    } else {
        $("#images").attr('src', imgUrl);
    }
})
```

https://codepen.io/DZuz14/pen/rzjxEO?editors=1010

Comment: If you are testing this on your local machine, you might be getting a CORS issue, which won't allow you to access that as well, but that is outside of the scope of your question. This will work if you have access.

Comment: thanks for the info I am using Zuver for my hosting will this be a issue? I was using crossingorgign.me but they have been having a server problem for the last few days and all other cors proxy's change the json format any ideas on a good one please?

Comment: Well, you might not even be having that issue anyways, you were just trying to set the image incorrectly. Refresh the browser with developer tools open, and see i you get a console error that looks something like this. Obviously your errors wont be the same as the pic, but it should give you an idea of what to look for. https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-IWB9szEnSqA/VhbOrINNedI/AAAAAAAC_Po/WwQ9C-IKVUg/s1600/2015-10-08%2B13_13_50-Store.png

Comment: just checked and it's there.

Comment: I am not really not sure of the best solutions, but you might be best off starting a new question and asking people on some recommendations for crossorigin issues, if there aren't already answers available on SO.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're missing a closing quotation mark in your URL.

Second, the website doesn't allow you to put javascript in people's browsers and make requests to it. This is a cooperative design with browsers and websites. You can see this error if open the console when making the request.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.airport-data.com/api/ac_thumb.json?m=C822AF. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Third, the `response` variable has more data to it than just what you've received. If you try this code:

```
$.get('http://www.airport-data.com/api/ac_thumb.json?m='+value.hex, function (response) { 
    console.log(response);
});
```

Then open your Javascript console in your browser, you'll see the object in the log with nested information. If you add "json" as the third parameter, it will instead make `response` into the data that you want, like so:

```
$.get('http://www.airport-data.com/api/ac_thumb.json?m='+value.hex, function (response) { 
    console.log(response);
    imageurl = response.data[0].link;
    if (imageurl == "")
        $( "#images" ).attr('src', "imageerror.jpg");        
    else 
        $( "#images" ).attr('src', imageurl);

}, "json");
```

But it wont work because the website doesn't allow cross domain stuff (unless you own it, and set it to allow your website).

Answer (score 1):

get 'json' via '$.getJSON' . [sample Link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp)

```js
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
var json='{"status":200,"count":1,"data":[{"image":"http:\/\/www.airport-data.com\/images\/aircraft\/thumbnails\/001\/288\/001288330.jpg","link":"http:\/\/www.airport-data.com\/aircraft\/photo\/001288330.html","photographer":"magnaman"}]}';
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
       imageurl = obj.data[0].image;
        if (imageurl == ""){
            $( "#images" ).attr('src', "imageerror.jpg");
        }
        else {
            $( "#images" ).attr('src', imageurl);

        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" >click</button>
<img id="images" src=""/>
```